# Prove that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, modules, injective-module

> **Problem:** Suppose $I(M)$ is injective envelope of $R-$module $M$. Prove that for each endomorphism $\varphi \colon I(M) \rightarrow I(M)$ has this property $\varphi(x)=x, \forall x \in M$ then $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

**My attempt:** By the hypothesis, we just check that $\varphi$ is an injective. For $x,y \in I(M)$ we have $\varphi(x) = \varphi(y) \Rightarrow x=y$ so $\varphi$ is an injective. Is my proof correct? I have to ask because my proof was very short and simple. Please check it, thank all!

Comment: You haven't properly checked that the map is injective.

Comment: I have edited it. $\varphi(x) = \varphi(y) \Rightarrow x=y$.

Comment: you only have that property for $x \in M$ not $x \in I(M)$. I would recommend using that you have an isomorphism on $M$ and then try to lift the inverse to an inverse on $I(M)$

Comment: @Enkidu Could you talk more explicitly?